# How are the many signals of a N64 or Wii joystick sent to the console by only 2 wires?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers, nintendo-64

I am curious as to how only 2 wires (perhaps 3 or 4) inside a N64 or Wii gamepad are able to send the many signals of the different inputs at once.

It used to be that for just one ON/OFF input, we needed two wires. So why does it not take dozens of wires for the many inputs on a modern gamepad?

Comment: How many can or how many are?  These are very different questions.

Comment: @tzenes The title is "How *the* many [...]", implying this is less about quantity and more about how it is able to do it all with only two wires.

Comment: @Grace it is awkward phrasing so I wanted clarification.

Comment: My digital TV arrives as a coaxial cable that has two wires, that carries a massive amount more info than a joystick's ever going to send!

Comment: Though @tzenes' answer about what encodings the N64 uses for its buttons is interesting, it does not really answer the question, which seems to be [How does multiplexing work?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing).  This question is [outside the scope of this site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), and should probably be closed.

Comment: @blue I disagree. I explained how the n64 controller sends multiple buttons on 2 wires. While a deeper discussion of multiplexing might be helpful it would be imspecific to his use case. As for whether or not this is on topic... We have meta for a reason

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the Wii Joystick uses a Blue Tooth interface which is a little different than the N64 controller.  As a result this answer deals more with the latter than the former.

---

The N64 controller uses a single transmission wire on which it encodes bits to send signals back to the N64 console.  To accomplish this bits are encoded on that wire as follows:

[image]

This encoding can then be used to multiplex the connection and allow 32 bit communication.  In the case of the N64 controller these bits are encoded thus:

```
0   A
1   B
2   Z
3   Start
4   Directional Up
5   Directional Down
6   Directional Left
7   Directional Right
8   unknown (always 0)
9   unknown (always 0)
10  L
11  R
12  C Up
13  C Down
14  C Left
15  C Right
```

With the remaining 16 bits being used for the Analog Joystick (providing 8 degrees of control).

More over, certain codes are transmitted for specialized function:

```
To Init: send 03 80 01 followed by 34 80's
To Start Rumble: 03 c0 1b followed by 32 01's
To Stop Rumble: 03 c0 1b followed by 32 00's
```

You can find more information in this vein [here](https://github.com/n64dev/n64dev/blob/master/docs/n64ops/controll.txt)

Comment: TL;DR version: serial communication

Comment: the wii is not very different, it still uses packages of data.

Comment: @alexanderpas - One could even argue that the Wii Classic Controller connects to the Wii Mote using a Serial type connector which communicates over a serial communication standard then transmited over Blue Tooth

Comment: oh if it uses bits... then 8 bits will allow 256 different signals... 16 bits will allow 65536... I just didn't think that the controller is able to communicate using digital signal

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is on-topic or not, but digital devices like joysticks send a digital signal by constantly changing the voltage in the wire from ON (usually 5V) to OFF and back at a certain time interval.

A sequence of on/off values like this is interpreted as a bunch of bytes which have some kind of meaning to the device.  For instance (totally invented example), pressing A might send "off off off off on on on on", which is the number 15 in binary.  The console would know that "15" is a code meaning "A button was pressed".

This all happens so fast that it seems instantaneous.

Comment: Is your on-topic concern about the question or your answer? If it's the former, [don't worry, it's on-topic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed).

Comment: Yes, the question.  Awesome, I wasn't 100% sure.